# Shortcut to grab window and move it?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, window

Is there a shortcut that once held while clicking on a window grabs it so you can move it? This exists on Gnome3 and is super handy to move windows around.

Comment: This was meant to be posted to **apple** stack exchange. Please someone move it.

Comment: – Just delete it from here and post it there. You can find delete link below the question.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Windows, which I assume you are using, does not really have a straightforward way to do this.

What might point you towards a solution:

1. Alt+Space - opens the title menu
2. R - to unmaximise if window was
   maxed
3. Alt+Space - open title menu again
4. M - to select movement mode
5. any arrow Key - to start "movement mode"
6. Move mouse - the cursors should jump
   and stay glued to the window will you move around now. *Might be
   that your system behaves slightly different, mine has a few hickups
   recently*

To automate this I suggest that you pack it in an [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) Skript. AHK has many different feature that could make this method actually "tidy". Maybe someone already has an AHK script for that. I searched only briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows?

As far as I know there's no direct way to grab the window with a keyboard shortcut. You can use the Windows-key and arrows of your keyboard to move the windows around your screen.

You can also just grab the top bar of your window to move it.

**Edit:**
I see you're on a Mac, in that case I'd suggest [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/).